# Using a popup to notify the user about successfully sending an email using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemailer

I'm trying to create a email form to add to a website using nodemailer. I have successfully managed to send the email to the desired the email and tried to notify the user that the message was sent using an alert but that doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.email + " " + req.body.message);
    var mailOptions = {
        from: ****@gmail.com',
        to: ****@gmail.com',
        subject: '[WEBSITE] Email from '+ req.body.email,
        text: req.body.message
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            alert("Your mail sent successfully!")
            console.log("email sent: " + info);
        }
    })
});
```

I followed the w3shcools page on nodemailer to get the email working. The html part is a barebones HTML form I created for the purpose of testing the code.

HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My question is how do you give a simple popup alert to the user saying the mail was sent successfully

Comment: Calling alert in the **server code** won't help. 
What you need is to **send a response** from the server to the frontend and use that response to display the email delivery status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert on server code will do nothing. you can send the json and handle it on the client side or you can pass in the script tag in response with the alert.

Try this this should work. (But this is not a recommended approach).

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.email + " " + req.body.message);
    var mailOptions = {
        from: ****@gmail.com',
        to: ****@gmail.com',
        subject: '[WEBSITE] Email from '+ req.body.email,
        text: req.body.message
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.send(`<script>alert("Email Sent Successfully.")</script>`);
            console.log("email sent: " + info);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. About the recommended approach you mentioned, can you suggest a place I can read more into it?

Comment: make the request through ajax and return json response from server.

Comment: Between if the answer got you out of the problem, make sure to mark it as solution.